# What do %@ and %ld mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

`NSString *expectedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%ld/%@"];`

What do the `%@` and `%ld` mean?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html A minute of googling brought this up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

%@ format specifier used for printing and formatting Objective-c Objects.

%ld used for Unsigned 64-bit integer .i.e. NSInteger.

Comment: Is is not solely for foundation objects, but for all objects.

Answer (score 5):

They are format specifiers.  Basically, insertion points for the rest of the parameters to `stringWithFormat`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html